# How do you change the name of folders that display?

Tags: ckfinder

In ckfinder the default folder names are the "names" of ResourceTypes defined in config.asp. There are three that comes by default - "Files", "Images" and "Flash". My question is if there is a way to change the name of folders that display in ckfinder ? Right now the name of the resource type is the default folder names, in this case "Files", "Images" and "Flash".

In ckfinder version 2.6.2.1 for ASP there is a config.asp file that has various resource types by default - 
Dim ResourceTypes(1) 
Set ResourceTypes(0) = DefineResourceType(
 _ "Files",
 _ baseUrl & "files",
 _ baseDir & "files",
 _ 0,
 _ "7z,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,‌​jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,‌​​xls,xlsx,zip"‌​, _ "" _ )

These names are used as Folder names in ckfinder. In this case "Files" is displayed as folder name

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about as far you got right now.

Comment: In ckfinder version 2.6.2.1 for ASP there is a config.asp file that has various resource types by default -
Dim ResourceTypes(1)

Set ResourceTypes(0) = DefineResourceType( _
 "Files", _
 baseUrl & "files", _
 baseDir & "files", _
 0, _
 "7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip", _
 "" _
 )
These names are used as Folder names in ckfinder. In this case "Files" is displayed as folder name.

Comment: CKFinder_Config.Add "ResourceType", ResourceTypes

Function DefineResourceType(name, url, directory, maxSize, allowedExtensions, deniedExtensions)
 Dim ResourceType
 Set ResourceType = server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 ResourceType.Add "name", name
 ResourceType.Add "url", url
 ResourceType.Add "directory", directory
 ResourceType.Add "maxSize", maxSize
 ResourceType.Add "allowedExtensions", allowedExtensions
 ResourceType.Add "deniedExtensions", deniedExtensions

 Set DefineResourceType = ResourceType
End function

Comment: Please put it in your question and watch its format

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using CKFinder 3.x: The `name` property of a [ResourceType](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/configuration.html#configuration_options_resources) is used as displayed name in CKFinder. The same was with CKFinder 2.x.

To change default set of `ResourceType`s in your application you should change it's [configuration](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/configuration.html#configuration_file) and define on set of `ResourceType`s.